# Something in master page causing postback to submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Something in master page causing postback to submit causing AJAX to fail.

I have these two drop down lists which postsback when the .master is not inherited on the aspx directive. I have searched all over SO and the net but the only thing I have found is that sometimes update panels have trouble working with validation controls.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlFaculty" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Faculty</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFaculty" EnableViewState="true" class="form-control" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" aria-expanded="true"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFaculty_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="null">Select Faculty</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Arts">Faculty of Arts</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Business">Faculty of Business</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Health">Faculty of Health</asp:ListItem>                      
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Industries">Faculty of Service Industries</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Trades">Faculty of Trades</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Maori">Te Wananga Maori</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ddlCourse" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Course</asp:Label>
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblfaculty"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdateCourse" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlCourse"  />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlFaculty" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>                          
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I inherit my .master, something in the .master catches and submits the data before postingback which means the whole page is reloaded.

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="IT7x11Project.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>                   
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>



            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>



        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting confused by your "question". Can you explain this bit better? "something in the .master catches and submits the data before postingback which means the whole page is reloaded"

Comment: I only know that its something in my master page because when I dont reference it it works fine